# Create array of ranges with loop, combine ranges to array of Fixnum

Tags: ruby

I'm looping through a set of `foo` that have a `starting_postion` and `size`

```
if ! foo.position.nil?
    @foo_top = foo.position + foo.size - 1
    @occupied_array = (foo.position..@foo_top)
  end
```

I see that I am currently reassigning the array on each loop.  My end goal is to combine all of the ranges in to an array of Fixnums so I can do a compare.

Should I just: `@occupied_array += (foo.position..@foo_top)` and then `@occupied_array.to_a` later?

Thanks

Comment: This is not a good way to ask a question. always input and output must have to be provided,with the code if anything you tried. Only code no way helpful us to help you out.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you have an array of `Foo` objects which each represent a range of integers by a start and length.  And you want to produce a single array of integers representing all the values covered by all of your `Foo` objects.

If that's true, try something like the following:

```
Foo = Struct.new(:position, :size)
all_the_foos = [Foo.new(10,3), Foo.new(3,3), Foo.new(15,5)]
p all_the_foos.flat_map { |f| (f.position...(f.position+f.size)).to_a }.uniq.sort

#=> [3, 4, 5, 10, 11, 12, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19]
```

Not sure whether the `#uniq` or `#sort` are desired, remove as necessary.

Comment: I think you have confused the meaning of `position` and `size`.

Answer (score 0):

Using this method you get to reduce seriously:

```
pos_size_pairs = [[1,5], [3,6], [15,2], [20,7]]
pos_size_pairs.map { |pos,sz| (pos...(pos+sz)).to_a }.reduce(:|)
=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 15, 16, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26]
```